# detecting any keystroke in applescript

Tags: applescript

I want my script to be listening/detecting any keystroke(any key pressed) via keyboard. If no key is pressed for about 5seconds, then continue to do something. Otherwise, keep on recording the keys pressed in a text edit.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In AppleScript you can't do that

Answer (score 1):

Since you specified TextEdit in your question, I wrote a script for you that checks for changes in a TextEdit document within the specified number of seconds. Do note that this only detects keys that input something into the document, so it's not *exactly* what you wanted. However, there's no way to detect *any and every* key being pressed in raw AppleScript, so this is the closest you can get (unless someone wrote a Scripting Addition or agent application to do that).

Here's the script, hope it is of use:

```
global lastText, lastTime, startTime

on run
    set lastText to application "TextEdit"'s (text of the document of the front window)
    set lastTime to current date
    set startTime to current date

    repeat
        if (checkForRecentTextUpdate given seconds:5) is true then
            -- Do something while the user is typing

        else
            -- Do something after the user has stopped typing

            exit repeat -- This is only an example
        end if
    end repeat

end run

to checkForRecentTextUpdate given seconds:secsRequired
    tell application "TextEdit"

        -- If midnight just passed, reset the last time
        if (the day of (the current date)) > (the day of the lastTime) ¬
            then set lastTime to current date

        -- If we just started, we can't judge; give a positive
        if ((the time of (the current date)) - (the time of the startTime)) < secsRequired ¬
            then return true

        -- If there have been changes since the last run, update info
        if (the text of the document of the front window) ≠ the lastText then
            set lastTime to the current date
            set lastText to the text of the document of the front window
        end if

        -- If the specifiied number of seconds has passed without any text updates, give a negative
        if ((the time of (the current date)) - (the time of the lastTime)) ≥ secsRequired ¬
            then return false

        -- If we got this far, there were changes in the seconds specified; give a positive
        return true

    end tell
end checkForRecentTextUpdate
```